# Get the minimum value in a user defined object

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
type candle 
    int index
    float Low 

for newLow in candle
    if (array.size(candle) - 1) > 5
        array.shift(candle)
 
// The error produced because of this line
minimum = array.min(candle)
```

The error message is saying that an argument of candle[] type was used but a float[] is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a few steps, you're trying to use array methods on a type. You can do what you're looking for a few ways.

This first way creates an array of your Candle type and then passes the Low of each candle into a float array so you can calculate the minimum.

```
 type candle 
    int index
    float Low 

var candleArray = array.new<candle>()
if bar_index > 0
    newCandle = candle.new(bar_index, low)
    array.push(candleArray, newCandle)
    if candleArray.size() > 5
        candleArray.shift()

float[] candleLowArray = array.new<float>()
for [ind,cl] in candleArray
    candleLowArray.push(candleArray.get(ind).Low)

clmin = candleLowArray.min()
```

The second way only creates one array and only pushes the candle.Low into it.

```
type candle 
    int index
    float Low 

var candleArray = array.new<float>()
if bar_index > 0
    newCandle = candle.new(bar_index, low)
    array.push(candleArray, newCandle.Low)
    if candleArray.size() > 5
        candleArray.shift()

clmin = candleArray.min()
```

Here's what I came up with to answer the question in your comment about getting the index as well, this will return both the low and the index

```
candleMin = 0.0
candleMinIndex = 0

for [ind, cl] in candleArray
    lowest = candleArray.get(0).Low
    lowIndex = candleArray.get(0).index
    for i = 0 to candleArray.size() - 1
        if candleArray.get(i).Low < lowest
            lowest := candleArray.get(i).Low
            lowIndex := candleArray.get(i).index
    candleMin := lowest
    candleMinIndex := lowIndex

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high, str.tostring(candleMin, format.mintick) + '\n' + str.tostring(candleMinIndex), color = color.lime)
```

Comment: Good answer. Is there a way to get the `bar_index` of the minimum value found in the array? The end goal is to plot a label `label.new()` of the minimum element within an array.

Comment: added another piece of code to my answer that will get you the index as well.